# How to hide/remove particular data from the Network tab in developer tools

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, frontend

[image]

I am working on React project and want to display the scores of an assessment, but the score should be anonymous (that is we should not be able to see the score of individual member. We should just see the overall scores of all members without the score being traced to their name).

I want to hide the `score` response from the network tab so that it is not accessible on the frontend. Is there a way I can do it?

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to hide the Network API calls from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should manage it from backend API response by managing what is the final data result you need and only send it.